# close mainwindows from QDialog

Tags: c++, qt

I've created two windows (a main window and a `QDialog`).
The dialog is created in the constructor of the main window. The problem is that the `QDialog` can be closed just by clicking the closing button so I'd like to do such that the main window closes too if I close the `QDialog`.

```
accueil::accueil(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::accueil)
{
   ui->setupUi(this);
   QPixmap bkgnd("C:/Users/jules/Desktop/projet_pharmacie/images/doctor.jpg");
   bkgnd = bkgnd.scaled(this->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);
   QPalette palette;
   palette.setBrush(QPalette::Background, bkgnd);
   this->setPalette(palette);

   log=new login(this);
   log->setModal(true);
   log->show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can show the dialog as modal, then connect to the close event to a slot/lambda and in that close the main window :)